# Rotation distorts my image

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

Im using CGAffineTransformRotate and UIRotationGestureRecognizer to rotate a view. The problem is that my view has a rectangular shape and at the moment of rotating, my view distorts and changes its shape. Im using this code:

```
- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
        recognizer.rotation = 0;

}
```

This is my original view:

[image]

And this is my result when I make a 45° rotation, I cant figure out how to make the view keep its original shape.

[image]

Comment: You're probably being bit by the autosizing junk.

Comment: Ive tried disabling auroresize subview in IB but seems to do nothing.

Comment: IIRC, the autoresize settings are concealed several different places.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

That was all I needed to stop my image from distorting when using `CGAffineTransform`.